# "Add Existing Item" feature disabled - how to enable / why does it happen?

Tags: visual-studio

I didn't use MSVS since v2008 (but I never was good at it). The version I'm talking about is 2012. I work mostly in Emacs, but for the team I must create MSVS projects and maintain them in a workable state. Now once I create a file, MSVS would not let me add it to the solution (click on "Project" in "Solution Explorer" -> context menu -> select "Add" -> "Add Existing Item" is grayed out.)

This used to work two days ago. Since then I've installed a plugin through NuGet that allows adding custom mime-types to IIS used in MSVS for ASP.NET projects. That was all the changes I've made.

How do I troubleshoot this? Why can this possibly happen? What could possibly be the reason for disabling this functionality?

**EDIT**

Sorry, it looks like it isn't possible to do it while "debugging" the project - somehow I must have fatfingered a debug session w/o noticing it. When I restarted the Studio, it prompted me about the open debugging session. After restarting the Studio the functionality was back. Still, it's strange you can't add files during debugging... or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Your project is compiled when debugging. Adding in files would be pointless as they would not be compiled. And we've all made that mistake and not noticed.

Comment: You can't make any changes while you're debugging. That's not really unexpected. And there are lots of things that change in the UI to indicate a debug session is in progress. I'm not really sure how you missed them.

Comment: @wvxvw F5 is that hotkey. =]

Comment: Because Emacs is a text editor, not an IDE. It might be a *fancy* text editor, but it's still just a text editor. You can open the code files in Notepad on Windows and make all the changes you want, too. Visual Studio is just not designed that way. It is a full IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today. The solution is to leave the debug mode in visual studio. Then the before grayed out menu point "Add New Item" project is available.

btw: you leave the debug mode in visual studio (2013) with Shift+F5 or click the red square in the gui.

Answer (score 1):

Add Existing option is disable when you are in debug mode please stop debugging then try to add existing item.